# Check if contact is from facebook iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, facebook, contacts

Is it possible to check if a contact(ABRecordRef) is added to the addressbook via the new facebook integration or not?

I want to filter away the facebook contacts, since I cant seem to add or edit the info on facebook contacts...(if this is possible? how I could do that would help aswell)

Comment: do u finde anything >>>>???